# Clarification on the gpg command (No such file or directory)

Tags: linux, command-line, gpg

I'm facing issues while executing the below command. Saying that No such file or Directory. I checked in the system and there were No such directory exist.

```
gpg: can't open `/root/.secrets/pgppassphrase.txt': No such file or directory
```

Whether the secrets folder need to be created first along with pgpassphrase.txt file present in that folder? Whether it should be a blank file or I need to enter the credentials that I need to use for the encryption?

Command:

```
mkfifo -m 600 /tmp/secure1 && (gpg --symmetric --batch --yes --passphrase-file ~/.secrets/pgppassphrase.txt --cipher-algo AES256 --output encrypted.enc < /tmp/secure1 &) && tsm settings export -f /tmp/secure1 && rm /tmp/secure1
```

Comment: It's easy enough to test, isn't it? Just create the directory and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You told gpg to use symmetric encryption and specified a passphrase file (--passphrase-file **~/.secrets/pgppassphrase.txt**) that doesn't exist.

**~/.secrets/pgppassphrase.txt** is expanded to **/root/.secrets/pgppassphrase.txt** because you most likely executed as root user.

If you want an empty passphrase (a.k.a password) you can use the "**--passphrase**" option with empty quotes. Otherwise place a passphrase in the file you specified.

```
gpg --symmetric --passphrase ''
```